# Добавление анимации css

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Вот нацарапал такой код

```js
function backcall(){
    var status = document.getElementById('backcallmsgdiv');
    status.style.display="block";
    status.style.height="100px";
    status.style.transition="max-height .3s";
}
```

```css
#backcallmsgdiv{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0px;
    -moz-transition: max-height .3s;
    -ms-transition: max-height .3s;
    transition:  max-height .3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap"><span id="backcallmsgdiv">
 Привет мир
</span></div>

<button onclick=backcall()>backcall</button>
```

Собственно сам вопрос - почему не работает анимация, при чём пробывал через @keyframes - тоже нет никакой анимации.

Comment: возможно, вы хотели добиться такого результата?
http://jsbin.com/jijufiloko/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: @ArkadiyAfonin да, но подскажите, ни как не могу увидеть ошибку у себя....Увидел, спасибо!

Comment: display: none -> block отобразит блок сразу же, проигнорировав transition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, ты анимируешь `max-height` вместо `height`. Во-вторых, `display` и `transition` скриптом менять вообще не надо.

Вот так работает:

```js
function backcall(){
    var status = document.getElementById('backcallmsgdiv');
    status.style.height="100px";
}
```

```css
#backcallmsgdiv{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0px;
    -moz-transition: height .3s;
    -ms-transition: height .3s;
    transition:  height .3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap"><span id="backcallmsgdiv">Привет мир</span></div>

<button onclick=backcall()>backcall</button>
```